# x mod -3 gives returns positive numbers

Tags: java, modulo

i want to get the negative number out of x mod -3 in Java.
e.g.: 1 mod -3 = -2 or 2 mod -3 = -1

Is there any method for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The `%` operator in Java is not the *modulus* operator, it's the *remainder*. (they're *not* the same thing) That explains the different signs that you're getting. From the current [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), section [§15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3):

> The binary % operator is said to yield the remainder of its operands from an implied division; the left-hand operand is the dividend and the right-hand operand is the divisor.
>
> In C and C++, the remainder operator accepts only integral operands, but in the Java programming language, it also accepts floating-point operands.
>
> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a.
>
> This identity holds even in the special case that the dividend is the negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its type and the divisor is -1 (the remainder is 0).
>
> It follows from this rule that the result of the remainder operation can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive only if the dividend is positive. Moreover, the magnitude of the result is always less than the magnitude of the divisor.

Answer (score 2):

`X mod -Y` as you've defined it can be calculated by solving `-X mod Y` and then negating the answer.

Example: `1 mod -3` -> `-1 mod 3 = 2` -> `-2`

In Java specifically, do `-X % Y`, then add `Y` if nonzero, then negate the answer.

```
public static int negativeMod(int x, int y) {
   if (y > 0) return x % y;

   int newAnswer = (-1 * x) % (-1 * y);
   if (newAnswer != 0) newAnswer -= y;

   return -1 * newAnswer;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that according to Java, `negative % positive = negative`

Comment: you should not add y if the modulo result is zero.

Comment: "I want negative number ..." --OP => then yes, y should be added even for a zero. Upvoted.

Comment: @JanDvorak I actually think you were right the first time, and edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Let's just say if OP _wants_ a negative answer, then he should delete the condition ;-)

Comment: Is there some reason you're using `-1 * n` to negate instead of `-n` like regular people? :)

Comment: I wanted to make it more visually obvious to OP

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. If the remainder isn't 0, subtract the modulus. For the example 1 mod -3, 1 - 3 is -2, the answer you desire. This is a simple consequence of the mathematical identity a == a - n (mod n).